# Is it possible to generate an unspoofable Hardware ID or a very difficult to spoof hardware ID? (i.e. buy a new PC part?)

Tags: c++, sql-server, hardware

I'm using C++ and working on my own game that uses mssql as a database (so yes I can store the generated hardware id somewhere). but thats not the point. Is it possible to generate a hardware id that cannot be spoofed, or to spoof the hardware id, it would require a whole new "motherboard" or "video card" for example.

Thanks so much pardon my ignorance I'm a new programmer. :)

example:

Say I make it generate a GUID when the user creates an account, I store it in my database. Simple. I then make that GUID not able to login to the game (Say they got caught hacking for example). They then create a new account. Will this new account generate the same GUID, meaning, well, they're still banned? (This is the outcome I'm looking for.)

I need to generate an ID that is tied to a users computer. I need it so it cannot be spoofed or will be difficult. The purpose of the ID is to block access to creating an account or logging into their already created account. I just want to know if I can generate an ID from someones PC, save it, and that they cannot change it.

Comment: Absolutely not clear what are you asking about. What exactly do you mean by _spoof_? Do you need to generate a hardware id that can not be _spoofed_? Or do you need to generate id that _spoofs_ some other id? Or do you want to buy a new hardware that would _spoof_ some other id?

Comment: I need to generate an ID that is tied to a users computer. I need it so it cannot be spoofed or will be difficult. The purpose of the ID is to block access to creating an account or logging into their already created account. I just want to know if I can generate an ID from someones PC, save it, and that they cannot change it.

Comment: You'd better edit this into the question, and the comment you left on LiamT's answer as well.

Comment: not sure how to edit a question. Edit: NVM got it lol

Comment: There is a `edit` link just below the question, above the comments.

Comment: Suppose there was such an ID. What stops a player from changing the part of your code that gets the ID, so that it gets a different IDinstead?

Comment: Some of us have several computers, How would you handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a GUID. GUIDs are numbers that are *practically* guaranteed to be unique.

Have a read of [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/). There's plenty of GUID generators out there if it is indeed what you need.

Comment: Say I make it generate a GUID when the user creates an account, I store it in my database. Simple. I then make that GUID not able to login to the game (Say they got caught hacking for example). They then create a new account. Will this new account generate the same GUID, meaning, well, they're still banned? (This is the outcome I'm looking for.)

Comment: No, the GUID will be different. 

What would they need to create a new account? Email? If so, why not just "ban" that? I guess it comes down to how do you know that the two users being created are infact the same person!

Comment: I have the option to ban by account. But making an account is free and I don't want my database to be spammed with accounts made my cheaters. So if I can permanently ban the cheater in the first place that fixes that. (hardware id ban! :)) I'm just not sure how I can generate a hardware ID that is not easily spoofed/bypassed.

Comment: He doesn't want a GUID. He wants "the" hardware ID.